# How to calculate chainlink VRF V2 fee cost?

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-vrf

I'm developing a contract on testnet using Chainlink's VRF V2.
I want to calculate the cost incurred when running on mainnet.

[image]

As shown in the picture above, a fee of 0.000523300633249633 LINK was charged.

[image]

look at the Transaction Hash information in Explorer, you can see that the gas usage is 110,208 and the gas price is 1.5(gwei).

From ChainLink VRF Docs:

***(Gas price * (Verification gas + Callback gas)) = total gas cost***

Chainlink VRF documentation states that the fee cost is calculated using the above formula.

But, I'm not sure **how to calculate the fee cost** for the transaction shown in the picture above.
And I don't know what **verification gas** means.

Can anyone explain in detail?

Comment: can you paste the polygonscan link or tx hash ?

Comment: 0xbc4ef57305eec262189e96f41da2ef1b14c281a89cfb7f373385935bfd3ac3b0
here Transaction hash executed by chainlink VRF.

Comment: Does this StackOverflow post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72261200/chainlink-vrf-v2-request-gas-fee-amount